# boost::async - unsure about the implementation

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, future

Looking at the new `boost::async` implementation in boost 1.52 I am a bit unsure about it's implementation for `launch::deferred`:

```
else if (int(policy) & int(launch::deferred))
{
  packaged_task<R> pt( boost::forward<F>(f) );

  BOOST_THREAD_FUTURE<R> ret = pt.get_future();
  return ::boost::move(ret);
}
```

I don't quite understand how this can work. Won't this always throw a `broken_promise` exception as soon as the `packaged_task` is destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document says it's "not implemented”.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.async