# Can't find what exactly do boost::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, std

I didn't find in boost documentation about **boost::async** for some reason.. Is it the same as std::async or there is some differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876459/boost-equivalent-of-stdasync

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look to [Boost equivalent of std::async()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876459/boost-equivalent-of-stdasync) and [boost::async - unsure about the implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327141/boostasync-unsure-about-the-implementation). Also, see [boost synchronization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html).